# Apache Karaf 2.3.4 and org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation package dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm trying to put a project on Apache Karaf but gets the following error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.acme.services.serviceA-impl [59]: Unable to resolve 59.0: missing requirement [59.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_60]
```

and my Maven pom.xml includes the following in the build-section:

```
<Import-Package>
    org.slf4j,
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation
</Import-Package>
```

Anyone have an idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: did you install the spring feature or bundle containing the required package?

Comment: you need to have the spring framework bundles installed in karaf. We already have spring bundles supporting till version 3.2.4. But if you need bundles with higher versions, you need to convert it, for example http://www.gharki.com/2014/04/how-to-convert-spring-expression-to.html

Comment: Thanks, Srikanth. Do you know if the same is possible using Karaf 4.x or why not? I know that Spring will not create OSGi bundles, but could it be done manually?